# Accessing Exchange Server using EWS - Admin rights required?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am going to develop a module using Exchange Web Service Managed API 2.0.

I would like to know whether we need to have ADMIN level permission to access the EWS web service? Can any account, access the EWS service or it requires ADMIN rights?

I am asking this question because the code I am going to write is going to access the Exchange Server 2007 using EWS.

Comment: I've tried using EWS as a "normal" user, and it worked. I used it to get my emails and calendar events.

Comment: When I access the EWS asmx, is it fine to pass any account (normal account)? I think it will require the username / password.

Comment: You must provide credentials for a mailbox in order to do anything with ews, and what you can do/see is constrained by the permissions of the principal whose credentials you are passing. You don't need the principal to have admin access.

Answer (score 1):

You need the login to the mailbox (usually primary SMTP and password), and that does not have to be an admin login.
There is also impersonation where you can login 'as another person'. You must then have the login information for the other and you must have impersonation permissions.

Finally, if user X shares his mailbox with Y, Y can login and access the mail from X. What he can do depends on the rights X gave him.